# Wait for an async function to return in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous, event-loop

Supposed, I have a async function in Node.js, basically something such as:

```
var addAsync = function (first, second, callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback(null, first + second);
  }, 1 * 1000);
};
```

Now of course I can call this function in an asynchronous style:

```
addAsync(23, 42, function (err, result) {
  console.log(result); // => 65
});
```

What I am wondering about is whether you can make it somehow to call this function synchronously. For that, I'd like to have a wrapper function `sync`, which basically does the following thing:

```
var sync = function (fn, params) {
  var res,
      finished = false;

  fn.call(null, params[0], params[1], function (err, result) {
    res = result;
    finished = true;
  });

  while (!finished) {}

  return res;
};
```

Then, I'd be able to run `addAsync` synchronously, by calling it this way:

```
var sum = sync(addAsync, [23, 42]);
```

*Note: Of course you wouldn't work using `params[0]` and `params[1]` in reality, but use the `arguments` array accordingly, but I wanted to keep things simple in this example.*

Now, the problem is, that the above code does not work. It just blocks, as the `while` loop blocks and does not release the event loop.

My question is: Is it possible in any way to make this sample run as intended?

I have already experimented with `setImmediate` and `process.nextTick` and various other things, but non of them helped. Basically, what you'd need was a way to tell Node.js to please *pause* the current function, continue running the event loop, and getting back at a later point in time.

I know that you can achieve something similar using `yield` and generator functions, at least in Node.js 0.11.2 and above. But, I'm curious whether it works even without?

*Please note that I am fully aware of how to do asynchronous programming in Node.js, of the event loop and all the related stuff. I am also fully aware that writing code like this is a bad idea, especially in Node.js. And I am also fully aware that an 'active wait' is a stupid idea, as well. **So please don't give the advice to learn how to do it asynchronously or something like that. I know that.***

The reason why I am asking is just out of curiosity and for the wish to learn.

Comment: not really. if you "hold the mic" in while, it can't execute the callback. if it can't execute the callback it can't set res. if you let up on the while so that it can execute the callback, flow slips out of the outer function and res returns before being defined. there might be a NPM tool to write code LIKE that...

Comment: What do you mean with *there might be a NPM tool to write code LIKE that*?

Comment: pseudo-sync code that looks procedural but internally uses callbacks to execute your described logic. i've done it myself with throw and Function, but that's a nasty habit to get into.

Comment: Do you have an example for code like that?

Comment: https://github.com/0ctave/node-sync, http://davidwalsh.name/sync-exec, or the hack i spoke of: http://danml.com/pub/sentry.html

Comment: dandavis is right, It's basically impossible to do real synchronicity in node. However there are some good libraries out there to do flow control. I'd recomend using this one: https://github.com/coolaj86/futures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use npm fibers (C++ AddOn project) & node-sync
- implement a blocking call in C(++) and provide it as a library

Yes I know-you know - BUT EVER-EVER-EVER ;)

Non-Blocking) use a control flow library

Comment: :-))) ... the problem is that there are situations where async is *really* ugly, and a blocking call would be less harmful than another level of indentation.

Comment: npm node-ffi could be an alternative - but it's also an C(++) AddOn ;)

Comment: @GoloRoden: if your async is "really ugly", look into IOC and Dependency Injection to unravel the spaghetti. Async CAN be just as clean as procedural code, with no nested callbacks.

Comment: Of course there are patterns that avoid nesting of callbacks, but - as pointed out in my question's example - I'd like to get rid of *any* callbacks, even the first one.

Answer (score 12):

I've recently created simpler abstraction *WaitFor* to call async functions in sync mode (based on Fibers). It's at an early stage but works. Please try it: https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

using WaitFor your code will be:

```
console.log ( wait.for ( addAsync,23,42 ) ) ;
```

You can call any standard nodejs async function, as if it were a *sync* function.

*wait.for(fn,args...)* fulfills the same need as the "sync" function in your example, but inside a Fiber (without blocking node's event loop)

Answer (score 0):

Standard propmises and yield (generator functions) will make this straigthforward:

http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/how-yield-will-transform-node

http://jlongster.com/A-Study-on-Solving-Callbacks-with-JavaScript-Generators